# convert shiny ldap authentication to flask ldap authentication

Tags: python, authentication, active-directory, ldap, shiny-server

We have shiny application which use ldap authentication from Microsoft Active Directory, which is as follows

```
auth_active_dir ldap://52.324.23.53/dc=x,dc=y,dc=z x.y.z{

        #user_bind_template  "{username}";

}
```

This code works properly. I have flask app. I want same LDAP authentication for flask app using following code

```
import ldap 
url = 'ldap://52.324.23.53'
l = ldap.initialize(url)
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
l.simple_bind_s('MyUserName', 'MyAnswer')
```

However following is error code, when I ran code in same machine.

> {'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580', 'desc': 'Invalid credentials'}

What I am doing wrong ? My UserName and Password I used are same one both places. Shiny Accepts UserName and Password. But flask throws error.

Comment: Is slapd service started in that machine?

Comment: Shiny server has no problem with authentication with ldap server. It is flask throws error.

Comment: The error is about the communication between your machine and ldap server, you need to make sure that your ldap machine accepts connections from your machine. check that you can ping it and that the port 389 is open.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated question.

Comment: Username must be something like "cn=MyUserName,..."

Comment: I have tried to use  "cn=MyUserName, dc=x,dc=y,dc=z", but didn't work